# How to use ellipsis text-overflow to fit height of card

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm trying to make my text fit the height of this card and hidden the overflow using ellipsis, as you can see if I use white-space: no wrap, it works but makes my block of text one line. If I use "normal" I get my block back but the ellipsis is gone... How can I achieve this?

```
<vx-card >
    <template slot="actions">
      <span class="text-grey">{{Time | moment("MM/D/YYYY, h:mm:ss a")}} 
      </span>
    </template>
      <p class="myoverflow" >{{PostContent}}</p>
        <div slot="footer">
          <vs-row vs-justify="flex-end">
            <vs-button color="primary" type="gradient" >View</vs-button>
            <vs-button color="danger" type="gradient" >Delete</vs-button>
          </vs-row>
        </div>
  </vx-card>
```

css:

```
.myoverflow{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

```
.myoverflow{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  white-space: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Rumor has it that you need to make a working sample to represent the issue.

Comment: I have added the html

Comment: I'm afraid it's not enough, still far away from the img.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should fix your problem:

```
.myoverflow{
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

jsfiddle attached:

https://jsfiddle.net/3d6fhrcL/